# How to install x264 for use with ffdshow

Tags: video, compression, codec

x264 isn't showing in ffdshow. I downloaded x264.exe. What am I supposed to do with it so that x264 will show in ffdshow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware you have to but it in the x264.exe in the same folder as ffdshow.

I have tried that and that has worked for me easily.